# SSRS IIF statement

Tags: reporting-services

```
= "All Business - Values - " & iif(Parameters!Limit.Value(0) ="N","Under 50k",
     iif(Parameters!Limit.Value(0) ="Y" ,"Over 50k", "All" ))
```

I have been trying to get this to work all day. Can someone please help.

I have a multi-select parameter of 'Y', 'N' and All to select both of them.

My issue is with the report header, I want it say 'Over 50k' when Y is selected and 'Under 50k' when 'N' is selected which it does correctly.

I want it to say "All" when both is selected but it is saying "Over 50k" whenever both 'Y' and 'N' is selected.

Please advise.

Comment: Which is the second parameter? I ask you this because you says "when both is selected".

Comment: I mean when Y and N is selected. There are no other paramters. I want it to say "All" when Y and N is selected. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are calling only the **first item** of your parameter collection. Try this:

```
= "All Business - Values - " & iif(JOIN(Parameters!Limit.Value) ="N","Under 50k",
     iif(JOIN(Parameters!Limit.Value) ="Y" ,"Over 50k", "All" ))
```

You can also use `Switch` statement for readability:

```
  = "All Business - Values - " & SWITCH(JOIN(Parameters!Limit.Value) ="N","Under 50k", JOIN(Parameters!Limit.Value) ="Y" ,"Over 50k", 1=1, "All" )
```

`Join` function displays the selected value of multivalue parameter.

You can use it something like these:

```
=Join(Parameters!Limit.Value)
```

Or to get comma delimited values

```
=Join(Parameters!Limit.Value, ", ")
```